# Removing users of a team in a denormalized Firebase structure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, denormalization

I have a some firebase data structured this way. It's really simple, but I can't figure out if there is an easier way of structuring it to add and remove members of a team efficiently.

In this case there are **users that belong to teams and teams that have users**. Pretty basic stuff.

```
users:{
    user1:{
        name: "username",
        profilePicUrl: "https://...",
        teams:{
            team1:true
        }
    },
    user2:{
        ...
    } 
}
teams:{
    team1:{
        name:"SuperTeam",
        members:{
            user1: true,
            user2: true,
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

I will make two queries. One asking for all members of a team and another one asking for all the teams of a member.

**In the interface I have a Multiple select where the user can choose the members of a team. The person will select/deselect multiple users and press a save button.**

When the user press save the following thing happens.

- I delete all the members of the teams table and set the new ones
  based on the selected options.
- I add the team to the selected users with
  "user/:userId/teams/:teamId" set => true

**But what about removing a team from the users table?** I can't figure out a efficient way to do it. My proposed solutions are the following.

- Updating all the users with a multiple update setting the teams to
  null or true depending on the select. This could work for a small
  set, but it doesn't seem very efficient for a large set of users.
- Removing the "teams" array in the users table and getting the teams
  of each user by querying "teams/:teamId/members/userX" equal to
  true. That way i only have to update the teams table. It works but
  it has to download all the Teams data, and for a large database is
  not very efficient.
- Look for changes in the selected options when the save button is
  pressed and update only the users that changed (my favorite so
  far).

**Is there another way to structure the database? Is there another option to remove a team from a member easily?**

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, and at first look, your database structure is good enough. What I can advise to make change in, is the fact that you're storing, the team which the user is part of in the `users` node, which can make the querying a bit difficult when there are multiple teams in existence.

You'd have to put false in many of them and put true in some of them according to your requirements.

You should rather just place the info about team in the `teams` node only and other relevant stuff about the user in the `users` node.

Also, if the team itself has a name, then naming it `team1` in the structure then giving the proper name, seems redundant from what you've told in the question.

So your database structure should look something like this:

```json
users:{
    user1:{
        name: "username",
        profilePicUrl: "https://...",
        otherInfo : ...
    },
    user2:{
        ...
    } 
}
teams:{
    SuperTeam{
         otherInfo: ...
         members:{
            user1: true,
            user2: true,
            ....
        }
    },

    MegaTeam {
         otherInfo: ...
         members:{
            user1: true,
            user2: true,
            ....
        }
    }

}
```

Now for removing a team say, `MegaTeam`, you just have to remove one node from the `teams` node, and the info about the members will be removed too, thus you don't have to query again to remove teams and other info from the `users` node.

**EDIT:**

Since you're using Firebase, (noSQL) the best thing is that you can alter the database and adapt it to suit your needs. So I'd say, the better way would be to put separate structure for getting teams with user.

Comment: And how can i make a query to get all teams from a single user? Like, give me the "user1" teams.

Comment: If you want to get teams with user, then it'd be better to use the structure you have. But then again you'd be making it hard to remove teams. See my edit.

Comment: @JoséNúñez do mark the answer as correct by clicking on tick mark looking V type button next to the answer, it should turn green. This helps future readers of the question and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)